# regex for files recognition for ffmpeg command

Tags: regex, linux, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg command to create a time-lapse from a bunch of images in a folder. The images are named in the format -
folder_number;timestamp.jpg
eg,
0;1423116000.jpg
0;1423137600.jpg

I run the following command, 

`ffmpeg -i %*.jpg -q:v 2 output.mpeg`

the video is getting formed but it is a 30seconds video with only the first image in the folder.

I only assume the regex i'm using - %*.jpg is wrong. Please help.

ps: I'm newbie to ffmpeg

Comment: remove the percentage mark. `ffmpeg -i *.jpg -q:v 2 output.jpg`

Comment: tried it without % ... still the same ... only the first image in the folder appears in the video

Comment: Did you check this page: http://www.astro.rug.nl/~sanderson/ffmpeghowto.html and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence#cite_note-1? Try `ffmpeg -f image2 -i *%d.jpg -q:v 2 output.mpeg` if you have your input JPG files numbered at the end of the file name.

Comment: it gave me an error could find no file with path '*%d.jpg' .... its numbered but not in a sequence, it's using timestamp the time it was downloaded it the format - folder_number;timestamp.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the command 

`ffmpeg -f image2 -i 0;%*.jpg -q:v 2 output.mpeg`

This did not work.
Renamed the files to have an underscore instead of semicolon.
Used the same command 

`ffmpeg -f image2 -i 0_%*.jpg -q:v 2 output.mpeg`

Worked.

Comment: `;` is treated as a separator. Quote the filename `"0;%*.jpg"`